# Mac Excel SUMIF #NA problem

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

A formula from a Windows based Excel sheet doesn't work on Excel for OS X:

```
=SUMIF(P2:P453,"<>#N/A")
```

The problem seems to be with the `"<>#N/A"` part.

How should that be written in Excel for the Mac?

Comment: Which version of Excel for Mac OS X?

Comment: I can't test on a Mac (only Windows, hence the comment), but try this quick array formula: `=SUM(IF(ISNA(P2:P453),0,P2:P453))` *(Note: To enter an array formula, type the formula into a cell and then hold Ctrl+Shift and press Enter)*

Comment: @DMA57361 tried that: gives `#N/A` as answer, also tried `=SUM(IF(ISERROR(P2:P453),0,P2:P453))` which gives `0` as an answer. Solved it in the mean time: different separator char on the Mac. Don't you love that :-)

Comment: @Daniel: Excel 2011 for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it; because Mac version of Excel 2011 is an English version of Excel with a Dutch locale, it wants a semicolon (;) as separator between the range and the criterion. Windows uses a comma (,) because it was English on an English locale.

This works on the Mac:

```
=SUMIF(P2:P453;"<>#N/A")
```

--jeroen

Comment: I assume it's locale dependent. In German locale, `.csv` files (comma separated values) actually use semicolon as field separator, despite the file type name.

Comment: Yep, on pretty much any locale that uses a comma as it's decimal separator Excel will use the semi-colon instead.

Comment: @Daniel, @DMA57631: thanks, I totally forgot about the Locale, I'm so used that an English version of Office is using an English locale, and a Dutch version uses the Dutch locale, that it didn't cross my mind users can have an English office with a Dutch locale :-)